# Elastic search 1.5 Geo point issue

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

We are trying to get geo distance sorting in ES 1.5. Our mapping for the geo_point type is as follows.

```
"geoPoint": {
      "type": "geo_point",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
 }
```

We add the index data as follows

```
"geoPoint":{
      "lat":18.5049,
      "lon":73.9005996
 }
```

When we check the mapping for elastic search after the document is indexed the mapping is different.

```
"geoPoint": {
    "properties": {
       "lat": {
          "type": "double"
       },
       "lon": {
         "type": "double"
       }
    }
}
```

We cannot sort by geo distance because the mapping changes.

Comment: Are you certain that the `geoPoint` field didn't exist before in your mapping? Did you create the mapping **BEFORE** indexing the very first document?

Comment: Yes I create the setting and mapping before indexing the first document.

Comment: Fixed it, when i tried adding the mappings from JEST client it did not work. Tried adding the same from terminal using curl and it works fine.

Comment: Ok, great you figured it out.